# Black screen on launch when migrating to SwiftUI application flow

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have done all of the refactoring to migrate from `SceneDelegate` to using a SwiftUI App and Scene with `WindowGroup`. I noticed that when the app is updated from the previous version, the app launches to a black screen, and you can't do anything with it. No matter how many times you quit and relaunch the app, nothing is navigable. I can log something in the `init` function of the `App` struct, but not in the `onAppear` modifier.

Uninstalling the app and installing it fresh works fine, but I don't want users to have to do this (I verified that this issue also happens when updating from my released app to a TestFlight beta).

Comment: Radar opened here with sample code. https://openradar.appspot.com/FB9692750

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to get around this seems to be to *leave* the info.plist configuration that tells it to look for the SceneDelegate class (`UISceneDelegateClassName`), but delete the scene delegate. This will cause warnings in the console on launch, but the black screen issue will stop happening.

Comment: So your app is converted to SwiftUI completely or you are using SwiftUI in part of your app?

Comment: Yes, this issue applies when the app is completely SwiftUI. (my app has a few ViewControllerRepresentable elements, but that's unrelated to this issue)